# Invalid Boot Signature after upgrade to 16.04 (dual boot windows 10)

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, signature

I'm lost not sure what to do here.... I don't know how to configure my secure booting options. I don't which setting to change?

Comment: I switch the boot order to Windows boot first rather than Ubuntu. Windows works fine.

Comment: If you turned Secure boot off, you installed Ubuntu with Secure boot off. There are three ways to install and they totally depend on the way you boot. UEFI with Secure Boot, UEFI and BIOS. Standard UEFI & BIOS are not shown normally if Secure boot is on. Invalid signature is system saying you are trying to use software that is not signed. You can upgrade Ubuntu to signed versions of grub & kernels with Boot-Repair. But may be easier just to turn secure boot off? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

Had to add a admin and user password before I could turn off safe boot. Grub 2 works perfectly now. Returned boot order to Ubuntu.